# graph contributor empty

Tags: git, graph, github, github-services

I have several projects on github, but in some of them the graph of contributors is empty, even though my .gitconfig has a name and email set up. 
https://github.com/jlengrand/batchWaterMarking/graphs/contributors

You can see on main page that I am authored on last commit, as jlengrand
https://github.com/jlengrand/batchWaterMarking

I tried to commit and push once again, with a .gitconfig I am sure about, but it doesn't change anything.

Because of this, masterbranch refuses to take some of my projects into account.

Would you know a way to solve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using multiple machines to push your commits? If the email and
name in your `GIT_CONFIG` is different for the different machines, you
have to add them to your GitHub account. You can add the different email
addresses under the [Account -> Settings ->
Email](https://github.com/settings/emails) menu on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am indeed using several machines . I tried to add all my emails addresses, but nothing changes :s.

Comment: And you were right. After adding all my emails addresses, I have to commit and push again to appear in the graph. Thanks !