# Merge commits on github from different users

Tags: git, github

I've been using github for a year or so and I've changed a bunch of computers during this period. I've been using only one account on github, but due to the different git settings github considers most of my commits to be someone else's. 
So I have very poor commit statistics though it's not. Is there a way to make github believe that all these commits is from my specific account?

Comment: I believe the following question might give you an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409083/graph-contributor-empty

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has the following script that will re-write the history of commits to fix the authorship:  [GitHub's Author Changing Script](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info)

A little manual work is involved in setting it up, but it should do the trick. The only thing is that this will effect the repository's history so all the forks will have to handle this accordingly.