# Github contributions not showing up on Repository Graph

Tags: git, github

https://github.com/tejas-manohar/fullcontact-samples

I've been working through the GH web interface (instead of command line and installed code editor on my computer) for this repository since its creation because I've been *on the go*.

For some reason, none of the contributor stats are showing here - https://github.com/tejas-manohar/fullcontact-samples/graphs/contributors - though they are showing on my profile, listed as commits, and seen seemingly everywhere else.

Does using the web interface have something to do with this? Maybe, I just need to give it a little more time? Something else?

Comment: Is this an email issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409083/graph-contributor-empty#comment13430947_10410610?

Comment: @VonC Not sure how it could be. I just created and started adding files and coding via the actual github.com web interface (not _best practice_, i don't do it often) but I'm on the go so it's convenient

Comment: Ok, then I suspect some latency issue: it should update itself soon, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was puzzled by this issue as it really just didn't make sense. As a result, I reached out to Github support and happily got the below response within 24 hours.

> Hello Tejas,
>
> Our Contributions system is currently undergoing maintenance. We will
>   get back to you after maintenance is completed and we can rebuild your
>   contributions data. Apologies for the inconvenience!
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Daisuke

Honestly, a nag of this should've been displayed right on the contributions page and the handling of this was extremely poor... but I'm glad we know the answer :)

Comment: Good feedback. +1. I deleted my answer.